# submit a value in a different 2 entities symfony

Tags: php, forms, symfony, doctrine

I'm trying to submit 1 form into 2 tabels.

This is my form:

```
  <div class="control-group">
       <label{% for attrname,attrvalue in attr %} {{attrname}}="{{attrvalue}}"{% endfor %}>Naam</label>

       <div class="controls">
            {{ form_widget(form.product) }}
            {{ form_errors(form.product) }}
       </div>
  </div>
  <div class="control-group">
       <label{% for attrname,attrvalue in attr %} {{attrname}}="{{attrvalue}}"{% endfor %}>Aantal</label>

       <div class="controls">
            {{ form_widget(form.amount) }}
            {{ form_errors(form.amount) }}
       </div>
   </div>
   <div class="control-group">
        <label{% for attrname,attrvalue in attr %} {{attrname}}="{{attrvalue}}"{% endfor %}>Serienummer</label>

        <div class="controls">
             {{ form_widget(form.serials) }}
             {{ form_errors(form.serials) }}
        </div>
   </div>
```

Formbuilder:

```
 $builder->add("amount", "number", array("label" => "Aantal"));
 $builder->add("product", "text", array("attr" => array("autocomplete" => "off", "data-provide" => "typeahead", "data-items" => "15", "data-source" => $dataSource), 'mapped' => false));
 $builder->add("price", "number", array("label" => "Aangepaste prijs", 'mapped' => false));
 $builder->add("serials","number", array("label" => "Serienummer"));
```

This is a part of my ORM:

```
   oneToMany:
        serials:
            targetEntity: SerialNumber
            mappedBy: BookingEntry
```

Here is a part of my 'BookingEntry' entity:

```
class BookingEntry
{    
    public $serials;

    public function getSerials()
    {
        return $this->serials;
    }
    public function setSerials($serials)
    {
        $this->serials = $serials;
        return $this;
    }
```

Here is a part of my 'SerialNumber' entity:

```
class SerialNumber
{
        /**
         * @var string $serial_nr
         */
        private $serial_nr;
        /**
         * Set serial_nr
         *
         * @param string $serial_nr
         * @return SerialNumber
         */
        public function setSerial_nr($serial_nr)
        {
            $this->serial_nr = $serial_nr;

            return $this;
        }

        /**
         * Get serial_nr
         *
         * @return string 
         */
        public function getSerial_nr()
        {
            return $this->serial_nr;
        }
    }
```

My BookingEntry tabel looks like this:

- Product_name
- amount

My SerialNumber tabel looks like this:

- bookingenrty_id
- serial_nr

Now I want to submit the serial number I insert into the form in the SerialNumber tabel.

I tried this in the controller:

```
$serialnumber = new SerialNumber();
$serialnumber->setSerials($form->get("serials")->getData());
$em->persist($serialnumber);
```

and this:

```
$bookingentry= new bookingEntry();
$bookingentry->setSerials($form->get("serials")->getData());
$em->persist($bookingentry);
```

But I keep getting an error that tells me that my query is empty.

But when I do this:

```
$serialnumber = new SerialNumber();
$serialnumber->setSerials($form->get("amount")->getData());
$em->persist($serialnumber);
```

The value off 'amount' inserts in the 'serial_nr' field.

Somebody got any idea?

Comment: What is relationship in both table? Which key is primary in first and foreign key in another?

Comment: sorry I left my primary keys out. Both tabels have an id column as primary key. And SerialNumber.bookingenrty_id = BookingEntry.id

Comment: Read about embedded forms: http://symfony.com/doc/current/book/forms.html#embedded-forms

Comment: You form has serials defined as a simple number.  You are expecting the form to somehow know that the value should go into Serials::serial_nr.  The form has no way of knowing it should do that.  You need to make a SerialsFormType and use it.  Work through the example in the docs.  And your persisting is all wrong but that should fall out once you have a form type.